# Grouping dataframe based on similar column values

Tags: python, dataframe

```
OFFENSE_ID    RULE_ID    STATUS  
       100          1      open
       101          2    closed
       102          2      open
       103          1      open
       104          2    closed
       105          2      open
```

Here's how I want it -

```
RULE_ID   OPEN   CLOSED
      1      2        0
      2      2        2
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What have you tried? Remember "How to ask a good question:" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You may want to do _pivot_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code generates the required output. It would make it easy for others to work on if you could provide the necessary script to simulate your scenario.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[100,1,"open"],[101,2,"closed"],[102,2,"open"],[103,1,"open"],[104,2,"closed"],[105,2,"open"]],columns=["OFFENSE_ID","RULE_ID","STATUS"])
df["OPEN"]=df[df["STATUS"]=="open"]["STATUS"]
df["CLOSED"]=df[df["STATUS"]=="closed"]["STATUS"]
dfGroup=df.groupby(by=["RULE_ID"],as_index=False).agg({"OPEN":"count","CLOSED":"count"})
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
dfinal = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on='RULE_ID', right_on='RULE_ID')
```